# Model values are null

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core

I have the following model:

```
[HttpPost("/case")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateCase([FromBody] Case model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest();

    _context.Cases.Add(model);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Success(model);
}
```

Here I post the following:

[image]

However, when it reaches the `model` has all the values set to `null`.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Update**

When i try to remove it so that my request looks like this:

[image]

Same thing happens

**Case**

```
    namespace API.Models
{
    public class Case
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int Size { get; set; }

        public long BuildingTypeId { get; set; }
        public BuildingType BuildingType { get; set; }

        public long BuildingPurposeId { get; set; }
        public BuildingPurpose BuildingPurpose { get; set; }

        public long ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public long LocationId { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }

        public long FireStrategyId { get; set; }
        public FireStrategy FireStrategy { get; set; }

        public List<CaseMaterial> Materials { get; set; }

        public List<Installation> Installations { get; set; }

        public List<DocumentationFile> Files { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the Case modle look like? Does it have the [DataContract] and [DataMember] Attributes?

Comment: I suppose the body should be { id, name, ... }, not the { case }

Comment: @ChristianSauer JSON.NET does not need DataContract/DataMember attributes

Comment: The payload is wrapped in an object with a `Case` property, but the expected model doesn't match that.  What if the top-level property is called `model` instead?  Or if there's no wrapping in the payload at all and you just send the `Case` object itself?

Comment: Ive updated my question @2k

Comment: Add the source of Case class to the question

Comment: Ive added the source of Case class

Comment: That `Id: null` could be the problem. Try to pass `Id: 0` instead

Comment: Also you are giving Size as string, but model expects an int. Do a breakpoint in controller, and check modelState, it should have all the errors that happened during binding.

Comment: I think it's in the json serialization.  Some mismatched data type.  For example, Id is null in the json, but it's not a nullable<long>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as it's already mentioned in comments, is that you pass `null` for a non-nullable property, thus model binder fails. You should either update model to have nullable property

```
public class Case
{
    public long? Id { get; set; }

    // rest of properties
}
```

or don't specify it in body (in this case it will have default value - 0 for long)

Answer (score 1):

The class you require from the body is inside another object, so it cannot be mapped to the class. body should be `{ id: null ...}` instead of `{ Case: { id: null ...} }`

Comment: When i try without i get the same result as before

Comment: Add the source of `Case` class  to the question

Comment: ive added the Case model

Answer (score 0):

When you post your model is should look like this

{
  ApplicationUserId: 1
 ...
}

what you are doing right now is that you are sending an object of Case inside anther JSON object.

Comment: I think we wrote in the same time, anyway it's good that you found the problem